# How to output value displayed on external webpage with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the value displayed on this webpage ([Loadshedding value](http://loadshedding.eskom.co.za/LoadShedding/GetStatus))

After I get the value I want to use a if/else statement to check the value, and then display the result in html.

The first Line is the only place I'm going wrong, I think:

**load.js**

```
var status = "http://loadshedding.eskom.co.za/LoadShedding/GetStatus";
var value = "Error1";

function checkStatus(){
    if(status == 1){
        value = "No Loadshedding at the moment";
        }
        else if(status == 2){
            value = "Stage 1 Loadshedding";
        }
        else if(status == 3){
        value = "Stage 2 Loadshedding";
        }
        else if(status == 4){
            value = "Stage 3 Loadshedding";
        }
        else{
            value = "Error";
        }
    return value;
    }
```

Then I'm outputting the result in html with the following.

**index.html**

```
<script>document.write(checkStatus())</script>
```

I just can't figure out how to get the value off  that page and check(if/else) and display it.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're literally comparing that link to the numbers. Just because you have a link as a string doesn't mean it's going to make a network call for you. Since you tagged this as jquery, I'll use that.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://loadshedding.eskom.co.za/LoadShedding/GetStatus",
    method: "GET"})
.done(function(status) {
    var value = "Error1";
    if(status == 1){
        value = "No Loadshedding at the moment";
    }
    else if(status == 2){
        value = "Stage 1 Loadshedding";
    }
    else if(status == 3){
        value = "Stage 2 Loadshedding";
    }
    else if(status == 4){
        value = "Stage 3 Loadshedding";
    }
    else{
        value = "Error";
    }

    document.write(value);
});
```

### EDIT FOR OP

Here's the entire page for you so you understand it better.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://loadshedding.eskom.co.za/LoadShedding/GetStatus",
                    method: "GET"})
                .done(function(status) {
                    var value = "Error1";
                    if(status == 1){
                        value = "No Loadshedding at the moment";
                    }
                    else if(status == 2){
                        value = "Stage 1 Loadshedding";
                    }
                    else if(status == 3){
                        value = "Stage 2 Loadshedding";
                    }
                    else if(status == 4){
                        value = "Stage 3 Loadshedding";
                    }
                    else{
                        value = "Error";
                    }

                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML(value);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Stop trying to use return. Don't use return. No return. Stop.

Comment: Would I use the same method to display the result on the page ?

Comment: @user2761473 literally use the code snippet I gave you and it'll do that.

Comment: Thanks so much!! I'll check it out. Can I use the same 'document.write(checkStatus())' to display the value ?

Comment: @user2761473 uhhh not in a way that you have it. When you make a network request it takes time for a reason to occur; it's an asynchronous operation. That's why you would should probably do it in the way that I had done it here with the callback function. It's not advisable to make it synchronous except in some specific cases.

Comment: I probably didn't explain very well, but that link goes to a webpage which just displays a number, between 1 and 4. I need to retrieve that number and then check against it. I'll look into synchronous and asynchronous operations though.

Comment: @user2761473  this literally takes that number off the page for you. This does EXACTLY what you need.

Comment: @user2761473 the `ajax` function call gets that webpage from the link and `done` takes a function with 1 parameter: status, which holds that number from the webpage. I am then comparing that number in the if statements. How does this not do what you want?

Comment: Sorry man, I'm a little new at this. I'm still not getting the value. I'm not sure if I should be adding anything like 'document.ready' or something in my js file ? I pastebinn-ed  this http://pastebin.com/AbgvfjTt. Should be JS file just have that in it ?

Comment: I'm just having problems passing the result of the JS file to my HTML page, as I need to display that string.

Comment: @user2761473 i updated the answer with _literally everything you need_. just copy-paste at this point.

Comment: @user2761473 you might need to change the url to be relative due to cross origin policy but i'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Ok, awesome. Thanks so much for the help. Seems like I am running into some cross origin policy issues, but I'm looking into that now. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery to get value. Replace first 2 lines of code with below code snippet to show the value

var value = "Error1";
   $.get( "http://loadshedding.eskom.co.za/LoadShedding/GetStatus", function( data ) {
            value = data;

});